# Android HttpsUrlConnection with multiple client certificates + connection pooling?

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, httpsurlconnection

In my application, I verify a the Android user's identity by giving each user a different client-side SSL certificate. I'd like to use HttpsUrlConnection to connect to the server since that's Google's recommended way.

The user can switch accounts (log out from the current one and log in with a different account). In this scenario, I need to estabilish the HTTPS connections with the new user account's client-side cert.

How will HttpsUrlConnection's connection pooling mechanism work in this environment? How can I force all HTTPS connections in the connection pool using the wrong client-side cert to disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

With the, err, disconnect() method.

Comment: According to the documentation, that method may return the created connection to the connection pool managed by the framework transparently.